# Correctly log protobuf messages as unescaped JSON with zap logger

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protobuf-go, go-zap

I have a Go project where I'm using [Zap](https://github.com/uber-go/zap) structured logging to log the contents of structs. That's how I initialise the logger:

```golang
zapLog, err := zap.NewProductionConfig().Build()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Initially I started with my own structs with json tags and it all worked perfectly:

```golang
zapLog.Info("Event persisted", zap.Any("event", &event))
```

Result:

```json
{"level":"info","ts":1626448680.69099,"caller":"persisters/log.go:56",
 "msg":"Event persisted","event":{"sourceType":4, "sourceId":"some-source-id", 
 "type":"updated", "value":"{...}", "context":{"foo":"bar"}}}
```

I now switched to protobuf and I'm struggling to achieve the same result. Initially I just got the "reflected map" version, when using zap.Any():

```golang
zapLog.Info("Event persisted", zap.Any("event", &event))
```

```json
{"level":"info","ts":1626448680.69099,"caller":"persisters/log.go:56",
 "msg":"Event persisted","event":"sourceType:TYPE_X sourceId:\"some-source-id\", 
 type:\"updated\" value:{...}, context:<key: foo, value:bar>}
```

I tried marshalling the object with the jsonpb marshaller, which generated the correct output on itself, however, when I use it in `zap.String()`, the string is escaped, so I get an extra set of '\' in front of each quotation mark. Since there's processing of the logs at a later point, this causes problems there and hence I want to avoid it:

```golang
m := jsonpb.Marshaler{}
var buf bytes.Buffer
if err := m.Marshal(&buf, msg); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
zapLog.Info("Event persisted", zap.ByteString("event", buf.Bytes()))
```

Result:

```json
{"level":"info","ts":1626448680.69099,"caller":"persisters/log.go:56",
 "msg":"Event persisted","event":"{\"sourceType\":\"TYPE_X\", \"sourceId\":\"some-source-id\", 
 \"type\":\"updated\", \"value\":\"{...}\", \"context\":{\"foo\":"bar\"}}"}
```

I then tried using `zap.Reflect()` instead of `zap.Any()` which was the closest thing I could get to what I need, except that enums are rendered as their numerical values (the initial solution did not have enums, so that didn't work in the pre-protobuf solution either):

```golang
zapLog.Info("Event persisted", zap.Reflect("event", &event))
```

Result:

```json
{"level":"info","ts":1626448680.69099,"caller":"persisters/log.go:56",
 "msg":"Event persisted","event":{"sourceType":4, "sourceId":"some-source-id", 
 "type":"updated", "value":"{...}", "context":{"foo":"bar"}}}
```

The only option I see so far is to write my own `MarshalLogObject()` function:

```golang
type ZapEvent struct {
    event *Event
}

func (z *ZapEvent) MarshalLogObject(encoder zapcore.ObjectEncoder) error {

  encoder.AddString("sourceType", z.event.SourceType.String()
  // implement encoder for each attribute

}

func processEvent(e Event) {
   ...
   zapLog.Info("Event persisted", zap.Object("event", &ZapEvent{event: &e}))
}
```

But since it's a complex struct, I would rather use a less error prone and maintenance heavy solution. Ideally, I would tell zap to use the jsonpb marshaller somehow, but I don't know if that's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`zap.Any`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#Any) with a [`json.RawMessage`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#RawMessage). You can convert directly the byte output of `jsonpb.Marshaler`:

```
    foo := &pb.FooMsg{
        Foo: "blah", 
        Bar:  1,
    }

    m := jsonpb.Marshaler{}
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    if err := m.Marshal(&buf, foo); err != nil {
        // handle error
    }

    logger, _ := zap.NewDevelopment()
    logger.Info("Event persisted", zap.Any("event", json.RawMessage(buf.Bytes())))
```

The bytes will be printed as:

> Event persisted {"event": {"foo":"blah","bar":"1"}}`

I believe that's the easiest way, however I'm also aware of a package [`kazegusuri/go-proto-zap-marshaler`](https://github.com/kazegusuri/go-proto-zap-marshaler) (I'm not affiliated to it) that generates `MarshalLogObject()` implementations as a protoc plugin. You may want to take a look at that too.

Comment: Is it possible to make it work with Desugar ?

logger.Desugar().Info("Event persisted", zap.Any("event", json.RawMessage(buf.Bytes())))

Answer (score 1):

I  used another way to jsonify protos.

Since protos can be naturally marshaled, I just wrapped them in the strict-to-json marshaler.

And you can modify the internals to use protojson (newer jsonpb).

Unlike the marshaler in the previous solution, this one doesn't require ahead-of-logging processing.

```
type jsonObjectMarshaler struct {
    obj  any
}

func (j *jsonObjectMarshaler) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    bytes, err := json.Marshal(j.obj)
    // bytes, err := protojson.Marshal(j.obj)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("json marshaling failed: %w", err)
    }
    return bytes, nil
}

func ZapJsonable(key string, obj any) zap.Field {
    return zap.Reflect(key, &jsonObjectMarshaler{obj: obj})
}
```

Then to use it, just

```
logger, _ := zap.NewDevelopment()
logger.Info("Event persisted", ZapJsonable("event", buf))
```